# Problem installing Ubuntu in Dell inspiron 9200

Tags: system-installation, dell

I have a dell Inspiron 9200 with Windows XP Professional and a pentium M chip. 
I have downloaded all softwares needed to create a bootable flash drive for the instalation of Ubuntu. I can only get to the section of the division of the hard drive after that it stall for the entire night. What is happening?

Comment: Try installink a more lightweight distro such as [Xubuntu](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)